# Compare two arrays in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I need to change the div's class name based on if condition below it.
i have tried as   `<div class="<?php echo $class_name; ?>">`
I want the class name to be "class name 1" or "class name 2" based on a if condition like if submitted and correct answer are same, i want the class name to be class_name1 or else it should be class_name2. The code is as follows:

```
 <element class="col-sm-6 col-aligncenter">
        <!--<div class="pipeline white lined-success">            -->
        <div class="<?php echo $class_name; ?>">
          <div class="pipeline-header">
            <h5>
              <b><?php echo $count++;?>. <?php echo $question_type == 'fill_in_the_blanks' ? str_replace('^', '__________', $question_title) : $question_title;?></b>
            </h5>
            <span><?php echo get_phrase('mark');?>: <?php echo $mark;?></span>
          </div>            
<?php if ($question_type == 'multiple_choice'):
                $options_json = $this->crud_model->get_question_details_by_id($row['question_bank_id'], 'options');
                $number_of_options = $this->crud_model->get_question_details_by_id($row['question_bank_id'], 'number_of_options');
                if($options_json != '' || $options_json != null)
                  $options = json_decode($options_json);
                else $options = array();
              ?>
                <ul>
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_options; $i++): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $options[$i];?></li>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
                  if ($row['submitted_answer'] != "" || $row['submitted_answer'] != null) 
                  {
                    $submitted_answer = json_decode($row['submitted_answer']);
                    $r = '';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($submitted_answer); $i++) 
                    {
                      $x = $submitted_answer[$i];
                      $r .= $options[$x-1].',';
                    }
                  } else {
                    $submitted_answer = array();
                    $r = get_phrase('no_reply');
                  }
                ?>
                <i><strong>[<?php echo get_phrase('answer');?> - <?php echo rtrim(trim($r), ',');?>]</strong></i>
                <br>
                <?php
                  if ($row['correct_answers'] != "" || $row['correct_answers'] != null) {
                  $correct_options = json_decode($row['correct_answers']);
                  $r = '';
                  for ($i = 0; $i < count($correct_options); $i++) {
                    $x = $correct_options[$i];
                    $r .= $options[$x-1].',';
                  }
                } else {
                  $correct_options = array();
                  $r = get_phrase('none_of_them.');
                }
              ?>
            <i><strong>[<?php echo get_phrase('correct_answer');?> - <?php echo rtrim(trim($r), ',');?>]</strong></i>

    <?php elseif($question_type == 'true_false'):
                  if ($row['submitted_answer'] != "") {
                      $submitted_answer = get_phrase($row['submitted_answer']);
                  }
                  else{
                      $submitted_answer = get_phrase('no_reply');
                  }
                  ?>
                  <i><strong>[<?php echo get_phrase('answer');?> - <?php echo get_phrase($submitted_answer);?>]</strong></i><br>
                  <i><strong>[<?php echo get_phrase('correct_answer');?> - <?php echo get_phrase($row['correct_answers']);?>]</strong></i>


**div's class should change based on if answer and correct answer are  equal**

There are two types of questions (multiple choice and true or false). It should behave same for both type of questions.
```

Comment: It is totally uncleared `I want the class name to be "class name 1"` or `i want the class name to be class_name1 `

Comment: That's just a indication. I need class_name1 if condition is true or if false, it  should be class_name2

Comment: "***div's class should change based on if answer and correct answer are  equal**"
Where is your condition to compare ```answer``` and ```correct answer```?

Comment: That's what i need to know.. where to add it since i don't know php or laravel much